# Kotlin - Data class entity throws StackOverflowError

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I try to combine kotlin (version 1.2.21) with spring-boot (1.5.9.RELEASE). I have encountered a problem using data class with @Entity annotation. My problematic entities look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
data class AppUser(

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true)
    private val username: String,

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private val password: String,

    @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE")
    val isActive: Boolean,

    @Column(name = "REGISTRATION_DATE_TIME")
    val registrationDateTime: LocalDateTime = SystemTimeManager.getSystemDateTime(),

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val authorities: MutableSet<UserAuthority> = mutableSetOf()
) : EntityBase(), UserDetails {


   internal fun addRole(authority: UserAuthority) {
      this.authorities.add(authority)
   }

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_AUTHORITY")
data class UserAuthority(
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "APP_USER_ID", nullable = false)
    val appUser: AppUser,

    @Column(name = "ROLE", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private val authority: Authority
) : EntityBase(), GrantedAuthority {

override fun getAuthority(): String {
    return authority.name
    }   
}
```

As you see, we have here @OneToMany relation between AppUser and UserAuthority. Now I try to add few authorities like this:

```
authoritiesCollection.forEach { appUser.addRole(UserAuthority(appUser, Authority.valueOf(it))) }
```

During execution first authority is always correctly added to appUser, however adding second authority produces StackOverflowError with a stacktrace

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at security.usermanagement.AppUser.hashCode(AppUser.kt)
at security.usermanagement.UserAuthority.hashCode(UserAuthority.kt)
```

If I make these class non data it works as it should. I probably can fix this by overriding hashcode and equals methods however I have many entities so I really rather not.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have a circular dependency between `AppUser` and `UserAuthority`. You need to exclude one to break the circular dependency when processing the hashCode.

You can fix it by moving the properties that cause de circular dependency to the data class body, that way those properties won't be used on the autogenerated fields. In this case, it would be moving `authorities` to the `AppUser` body:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
data class AppUser(

        @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = true)
        private val username: String,

        @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
        private val password: String,

        @Column(name = "IS_ACTIVE")
        val isActive: Boolean,

        @Column(name = "REGISTRATION_DATE_TIME")
        val registrationDateTime: LocalDateTime = SystemTimeManager.getSystemDateTime(),

) {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    val authorities: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()

    internal fun addRole(authority: String) {
        this.authorities.add(authority)
    }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's no working. Probably because data classes are not managed by lombok (due @Data annotation) only by kotlin itself.

Comment: updated my answer to avoid using @EqualsAndHashCode from lombok

Comment: Well technically it is a correct answer, however as I state in my question I do have lots of entities and many of them have circular dependencies. So I was searching for some kind of annotation or some library which would allow me to bypass overriding equals and hashcode for every entity.

Comment: My bad, according to data classes documentation if you could declare a property in the class body it won't be used inside the automatically generated functions. Maybe you can give it a try moving `val authorities` to the AppUser body.

Comment: It is working, however it must be stated that this solution also has it's cons. You would need a secondary constructor or some other solution to init the param which you have extracted from primary constructor and it is somehow redundant but less redundant then overriding equals and hashcode over and over again. Biggest dissapoiment however is that you no longer can use copy method with that extracted param. Only parameters in primary constructor of data class could be changed in the copy method.

Comment: Just a subnote, be careful when using copy method for example because then the values inside body are not copied rather reinitialized to their default value. Should not be problem for bidirectional relationships when the owning side has the field inside class parameters.