# One to Many / Many to one relationship isn't saved in Kotlin, while it is in Java

Tags: kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have a Kotlin project..

I added the [complete code to github](https://github.com/joergi/tryouts/tree/main/jpa_kotlin), so you can download it to play around.

there are 2 Entities:
Band

```
@Entity
data class Band(

    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    val id: Int? = null,

    var name: @NotEmpty(message = "name must not be empty") String? = null,

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
                mappedBy = "band",
                cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    val links: Set<Link> = mutableSetOf()
)
```

Links

```
@Entity
data class Link(

    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    val id: Int? = null,

    var url: String? = null,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "band_id", nullable = true)
    var band: Band? = null

)
```

SQL looks like this:

```
create table band
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
);

create table link
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY not null,
    band_id int,
    url varchar(100) not null,

    CONSTRAINT "fk_band_links" FOREIGN KEY ("band_id") REFERENCES "band" ("id")    
);
```

I create a band like this for my test (in `BandUtils.kt`)

```
fun createBandWithLinks(): Band {
        val link1 = Link()
        link1.url = "https://fb.com/"

        val link2 = Link()
        link2.url = "https://twitter.com/"

        return Band(
            name = "Band with links",
            links = mutableSetOf(link1,link2),
        )
    }
```

When I save the data:

```
bandRepository!!.save(BandUtils.createBandWithLinks())
```

I expect, that the links and the bands are saved!
This works.

But I can't see the bands in the link table.

I made the same thing before in Java, and I also see the examples from [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) work like this.

Is there any difference between Kotlin and Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem 1. Persisting bidirectional relationship Band=Link**

In the case of a bidirectional relationship Hibernate (or JPA implementations) cares only about the owning side of the association. The owning side is the side that doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute!

So if we only call `band.links = LinkUtils.createListOfLinks()`, the `Band` will not be linked to the new `Link` entity, because this is not the owning /tracked side of the relation.

You need to explicitly set `Band` for `Link`, call `link.band = band`, because that is the owning side of the relation.

When using `mappedBy`, it is the responsibility of the developer to know what is the owning side, and update the correct side of the relation in order to trigger the persistence of the new relationship in the database.

There are no differences between Java and Kotlin. It is JPA specification.

**Solution 1: set relation from both sides**

Correct Utils to set relation from both sides

```kotlin
object BandUtils {
    fun createBandWithLinks(): Band {
         val band = Band(
            name = "MEA with links",
            description = "merch em all"
            )
        band.links = LinkUtils.createListOfLinks(band)
        return band
    }
}

object LinkUtils {
    fun createListOfLinks(band: Band): MutableSet<Link> {
        val link1 = Link()
        link1.url = "https://fb.com/joergi"
        link1.band = band

        val link2 = Link()
        link2.url = "https://twitter.com/joergi"
        link2.band = band

        var linkSets = mutableSetOf<Link>()
        linkSets.add(link1)
        linkSets.add(link2)
        return linkSets
    }
}
```

**Solution 2: change the owning side of the relation (NOT recommended)**

No need to change your utils.

Remove `mappedBy` for `OneToMany`, add `JoinColumn`

```kotlin
    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
       // mappedBy = "band",
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "band_id")
    var links: MutableSet<Link> = mutableSetOf()
```

Add `JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)` for `ManyToOne`

```kotlin
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "band_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    var band: Band? = null
```

Entities definition

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Band(

    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    val id: Int? = null,

    var name: @NotEmpty(message = "name must not be empty") String? = null,

    var description: String? = null,

    @JsonBackReference(value = "links")
    @OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = [CascadeType.ALL]
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "band_id")
    var links: MutableSet<Link> = mutableSetOf()
}

@Entity
data class Link(

    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    val id: Int? = null,


    var url: String? = null

) {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "band_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    var band: Band? = null
}
```

In your [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many#many-to-one) article this problem is described in item 6.

**Problem 2. Bidirectional relationship data class circular dependency for toString and hashCode**

When you perform the correct creation of your entities you will receive `StackOverflow` error during persisting because you have bidirectional relations and entities defined like `data class`. Kotling will generate incorrect `hashCode` implementation which moves into an infinity loop during execution for bidirectional entities.

**Solution 1: Lombok**

Use `Lombok` instead of `data class` and ignore one relation side

```kotlin
@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude=["band"])
@ToString(exclude = ["band"])
class Link
```

```kotlin
@Entity
@Data
class Band
```

**Solution 2: move the properties that cause de circular dependency to the data class body**

See details [Kotlin - Data class entity throws StackOverflowError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48926704/kotlin-data-class-entity-throws-stackoverflowerror)

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Link(

    @Id
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Schema(hidden = true)
    val id: Int? = null,


    var url: String? = null

) {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "band_id", nullable = true)
    var band: Band? = null
}
```

**UPDATE**

**Why changing owning side is not a good solution?**

Its influences on the count of generated queries and as a result on performance.

**3 Queries** generated in case owning side is `ManyToOne`:

```sql
Hibernate:
    insert 
    into
        band
        (id, description, name) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        link
        (id, band_id, url) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        link
        (id, band_id, url) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?)
```

**5 Queries** generated in case owning side is `OneToMany`:

```sql
Hibernate:
  insert 
    into
        band
        (id, description, name) 
    values
        (default, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        link
        (id, url) 
    values
        (default, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        link
        (id, url) 
    values
        (default, ?)
Hibernate: 
    update
        link 
    set
        band_id=? 
    where
        id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        link 
    set
        band_id=? 
    where
        id=?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this long answer. I will try both variations and see what fits best in the next few. Can you maybe explain, why solution 2 is not recommend?

Comment: Hi, Its influences on the count of generated queries and as a result on performance. On the huge project, it can be significant. I updated the answer with a detailed explanation.

Comment: wow, I now went through the code again... how could I have missed the option to sent Band to create links? that makes totally sense...
Thanks again for the great explanations. the bounty is totally deserved!